# How to filter in Nested Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a filter menu. I have an Object something like below. From my filter menu I will get an object result:

```
{gm: "FS H", rm: "RSM1", am: "BKK PULL", sales: "BKK SR1", state: "delhi", …}
```

From this result I need to find the associated sa_id and pr_id.
From above result: gm is top menu. rm is filtered based on gm selected.

Given is my whole object. Now I dont know how to filter to get my id.

```
{
"FS H": {
    "RSM1": {
        "BKK PULL": {
            "BKK SR1": {
                mumbai: {
                    sa_id: 34,
                    pr_id: 12
                },
                delhi: {
                    sa_id: 12,
                    pr_id: 32
                }
            }
        },
        "BKK PUSH": {
            "BKK BCDE1": [],
            "BKK BAKE SE1": []
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: This is not an array - this is an object.

Comment: sorry its object

Comment: please add the wanted result, a data set for testing, your code and what goes wrong.

Comment: A user with your rep should know that SO is not for *I want*. Its for *I'm stuck here*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest approach I can think of for the moment.

You can improve it anyhow you want as this is just a guide for you.

```js
const filter = {
  gm: "FS H",
  rm: "RSM1",
  am: "BKK PULL",
  sales: "BKK SR1",
  state: "delhi"
}

const data = {
  "FS H": {
    "RSM1": {
      "BKK PULL": {
        "BKK SR1": {
          mumbai: {
            sa_id: 34,
            pr_id: 12
          },
          delhi: {
            sa_id: 12,
            pr_id: 32
          }
        }
      },
      "BKK PUSH": {
        "BKK BCDE1": [],
        "BKK BAKE SE1": []
      }
    },
  }
}

console.log(data[filter.gm][filter.rm][filter.am][filter.sales][filter.state])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of the needed keys in the right order and reduce the given object with the values of the filter object.

The result is an object with the wanted ids, or `undefined`.

```js
function getID(filter) {
    var keys = ['gm', 'rm', 'am', 'sales', 'state'];
    return keys.reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[filter[k]], data);
}

var data = { "FS H": { "RSM1": { "BKK PULL": { "BKK SR1": { mumbai: { sa_id: 34, pr_id: 12 }, delhi: { sa_id: 12, pr_id: 32 } } }, "BKK PUSH": { "BKK BCDE1": [], "BKK BAKE SE1": [] } } } },
    result = getID({ gm: "FS H", rm: "RSM1", am: "BKK PULL", sales: "BKK SR1", state: "delhi" });

console.log(result);
```